# how to make div's height expand with a child div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id='main'>
         <div id='mid'>
             <p>
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                 Quisque feugiat ante et purus ullamcorper dignissim. Aenean 
                 aliquet leo eu risus fringilla gravida vel a elit. Etiam 
                 congue lectus eu condimentum elementum. Cras sit amet ipsum 
                 commodo, fermentum quam vitae, feugiat orci. Donec quis 
                 venenatis quam, id consectetur eros. Cras rhoncus ut massa 
                 et euismod. Nunc at felis arcu. Pellentesque consequat 
                 augue ac nulla hendrerit egestas.
                 Donec auctor erat eu consectetur sodales. Sed sodales quam 
                 eget lectus fringilla, et semper odio pretium. Sed tempus 
                 suscipit tempus. 
             </p>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
        body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #main {
            display:block;
            width:100%;
            min-height:100%;
            background-color:black;
            opacity:0.85;
        }
        #mid {
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            margin:0 auto;
            width:88%;
            background-color:#558000;
            opacity:1;
        }
        p {
            margin:4vw 8vw 4vw 8vw;
            font-size:30px;
            font-family:trebuchet ms;
            color:white;
        }
    </style>
```

The paragraph is just to make "mid" long enough to show that it actually goes past the bottom of the parent element "main". I can't seem to figure out how to make "main" expand along with "mid". "mid" expands to fit the whole paragraph into it, though I don't know why "main" doesn't do the same with "mid".

Comment: You have positioned `#mid` 'absolutely' which means its taken out of the normal 'flow' of the page so, `#main` doesnt actually recognise there is a div inside it, which is why `#main` isnt expanding to the same height as `#mid`is there a reason you are positioning `#mid` absolutely? if you remove it, it will fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
#mid {
  position:absolute;
}
```

the `#main` will lose his height because you didn't set one, the `width` is `100%` because you set `display: block`. So you have just to remove `position: absolute;` from `#mid` element.

Here a [fiddle on this](https://jsfiddle.net/gswohpf1/11/).